# Seagate 4TB USB HDD not auto-mounted - reformat or not?

Tags: ntfs, external-hdd, automount, ext4

Just got a Seagate 4TB USB HDD for back-ups, and it's not automatically mounted by 16.04 xenial.

This is what I'm seeing from dmesg:

```
[ 4332.436035] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 4332.569699] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab28
[ 4332.569704] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 4332.569706] usb 2-1: Product: BUP BK
[ 4332.569708] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 4332.569710] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: NA7P6M67
[ 4332.570939] scsi host9: uas
[ 4332.573015] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP BK           0304 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4332.574788] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[ 4332.575567] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Spinning up disk...
[ 4333.576031] .....ready
[ 4337.592589] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] 7814037167 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[ 4337.592594] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] 2048-byte physical blocks
[ 4337.670470] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 4337.670476] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[ 4337.671201] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 4337.830069] Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.
[ 4337.830089]  sdd: sdd1 sdd2
[ 4337.834193] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

***UPDATE - day after***

```
[47837.368954] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

and then in fdisk:

```
adam@gondor:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdd
[sudo] password for adam: 
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdd: 3.7 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 10EA27FC-6BA7-49C5-BD29-A7F10C16B330

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdd2  264192 7814035455 7813771264  3.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
adam@gondor:~$
```

Is this error with the 'Alternate GPT' the issue?

Shall I reformat it with `ext4`? Are there any particular issues with the 4TB size?

Comment: In Ubuntu Nautilus, does it appear in the left pane of a files window? If so, just click on it. That should mount it. Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, boot Windows and run a `chkdsk /f d:` on the drive (changing the "d" to the correct drive letter, if different). In any case, I'd copy off any diag/backup apps they put on there for the user, and re-init it anyway before I'd use it.

Comment: Strange, it didn't appear there yesterday but it does today. I don't use Windows at all, in fact I have no computers running it at all. But you would re-init it? That means reformat? As `ext4`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `gparted` which comes with the Ubuntu live drive, but must be installed in an installed Ubuntu system. Create a GUID partition table, GPT, and at least one partition. **NTFS** is a good file system, if you intend to share data with Windows (for example in another computer). If you intend to use only linux, **ext4** is a good file system.

Comment: We don't reformat now-a-days. But yes, re-init by doing as sudodus suggests. New partition table, new partition. Do you want me to make this into an answer so you can vote/accept?

Comment: @Adam I went ahead and did an answer for you. Please vote/accept if you think it was useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the comments...

If you dual-boot with Windows, open a admin command console and type `chkdsk /f d:` (changing the "d" to the appropriate drive letter) to check the disk.

In Ubuntu, the drive will appear in the left pane of a Nautilus files window, and you can click on it to mount the drive.

As with any newly purchased drive, I would always recommend that you reinitialize it using `gparted`. Launch it from the Unity dashboard. If it's not already installed, in `terminal` type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then use `gparted` to lay down a new GPT partition table, and create fresh new partition(s) as you like. Use NTFS for a drive shared with a Windows system, or EXT4 for a Ubuntu only configuration.

You'll have to edit `/etc/fstab` to make it auto-mount at boot time. Something similar to:

```
sudo blkid # to obtain the correct UUID number
sudo mkdir /media/username/some_mountpoint_name # for drives owned by root
sudo chown username: /media/username/some_mountpoint_name # for drives owned by username
```

and add something similar to one of these to `/etc/fstab`...

```
# shared EXT4 disk
UUID=correct_UUID_# /media/username/some_mountpoint_name   EXT4      defaults   0    2

# shared ntfs disk
UUID=correct_UUID_# /media/username/some_mountpoint_name   ntfs-3g   defaults   0    0
```

Comment: Creating the mount-point for drives owned by `username`: The directory `/media/username`is normally owned by `root` and has the permissions `drwxr-x---+`, you can't create a directory in it without root-privileges, so better to use `sudo mkdir  /media/username/some_mountpoint_name` and then `sudo chown username:  /media/username/some_mountpoint_name`.

Comment: @mook765 please review my edit to see if I've got it right. Thanks!

Comment: That looks good now...

Comment: Are you sure I'll have to edit `/etc/fstab` to make it auto-mount? Or is that only at boot time? I'm not too concerned about that since it's a USB drive, but I suppose there's a strong chance I'll leave it connected during reboots.

Comment: @Adam try booting with the drive connected, and see. Also, if it's EXT4, it'll get fsck checked at boot time, if it's in fstab. If there's a strong chance that the drive will not be connected at all times, then don't put it in fstab.

Comment: Done that with gparted, but before the drive was titled "Seagate Backup Plus Drive", and now it just comes up as "4TB Drive" in the File Manager (I use PCManFM, not Nautilus). Checking in gparted, I couldn't see how to label it. That must be an fdisk thing, right?

Comment: Nope, not fdisk either

Comment: You can name the partition in gparted, or use something like `sudo tune2fs -L my_name /dev/sdb1`.

Comment: Well I did name it in gparted but it didn't have any effect either in the file manager GUI or in the name that appeared in /media/adam.  `tune2fs` did work though.